# Create Quantum elixir jobs

Tags: elixir, cron-task

I want to create a quantum elixir job and control the time it is executed. I started with this:

```
Quantum.Job.new(task: fn -> IO.puts "Hello!" end)
```

but it throws this error:

```
** (KeyError) key :run_strategy not found in: [task: #Function<20.99386804/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>]
    (elixir) lib/keyword.ex:371: Keyword.fetch!/2
    (quantum) lib/quantum/job.ex:58: Quantum.Job.new/1
```

I really don't understand the run_strategy setting and it's possible values.

Does somebody knows how to create a quantum job using the struct of Quantum.Job.new or something similar?

NOTE: the cron is already working using this:

```
config :sopitas, Sopitas.Scheduler,
  jobs: [
    # Every minute
    {"@minutely", {Sopitas.Admin.FixtureController, :update_cron, []}},
    {"@minutely", {Sopitas.Admin.StandingController, :update_cron, []}},
    {"@daily", {Sopitas.Admin.LeagueController, :update_cron, []}},
  ]
```

but the point is to change the time the cron is executed, that's why I decided to create it using Quantum.Job.new

Answer (score 3):

The solution was easier than I thought. The Quantum documentation says:

> config :your_app, YourApp.Scheduler,   jobs: [
>            # Every minute
>            {"* * * * *",      {Heartbeat, :send, []}},
>
>            # Every 15 minutes
>
>            {"*/15 * * * *",   fn -> System.cmd("rm", ["/tmp/tmp_"]) end},
>            # Runs on 18, 20, 22, 0, 2, 4, 6:
>            {"0 18-6/2 * * *", fn -> :mnesia.backup('/var/backup/mnesia') end},
>            # Runs every midnight:
>            {"@daily",         {Backup, :backup, []}}   
>   ]

I changed the tuples by lists, so I can name each job. I can fetch them by their names and change their schedules:

```
config :sopitas, Sopitas.Scheduler,
  jobs: [
    [name: :redis_cleaning, schedule: "@daily", task: {Sopitas.NotificationController, :clear_redis, []}],
    [name: :fixtures, schedule: "@daily", task: {Sopitas.Admin.FixtureController, :update_cron, []}],
    [name: :standings, schedule: "@daily", task: {Sopitas.Admin.StandingController, :update_cron, []}],
    [name: :leagues, schedule: "@daily", task: {Sopitas.Admin.LeagueController, :update_cron, []}],
    # [name: :example_cron, schedule: "@minutely", task: fn -> IO.puts "Hello!" end],
  ]
```

I created a function which handles the jobs:

```
  def change_cron(name, cron_expression) do
    job = Sopitas.Scheduler.find_job(name)
    unless job do
      Quantum.Job.set_schedule(job, Crontab.CronExpression.Parser.parse! cron_expression)
    end
  end
```

I call that function as follows:

```
Sopitas.SportsController.change_cron :fixtures, "@daily"
Sopitas.SportsController.change_cron :fixtures, "@minutely"
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first sentence in the [`Quantum.Job`](https://hexdocs.pm/quantum/Quantum.Job.html#content) doc says:

> The struct should never be defined by hand. Use `Acme.Scheduler.new_job/0` to create a new job and use the setters mentioned below to mutate the job.

The `Quantum.Job` itself is a `struct` with [three mandatory keys](https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir/blob/v2.0.3/lib/quantum/job.ex#L17):

```
@enforce_keys [:run_strategy, :overlap, :timezone]
```

If you are still positive you want to violate their guidelines, you should pass these three keywords, like:

```
Quantum.Job.new(
  task: fn -> IO.puts "Hello!" end,
  run_strategy: %Quantum.RunStrategy.All{nodes: [:one, :two]},
  timezone: "Europe/Zurich",
  overlap: false
)
```

I would suggest you use one of the examples provided [here](https://hexdocs.pm/quantum/Quantum.Job.html#content), though.

Comment: You're right, the problem is that I cannot use Acme.Scheduler module

`iex(6)> Acme.Scheduler.config |> Quantum.Job.new
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Acme.Scheduler.config/0 is undefined (module Acme.Scheduler is not available)
    Acme.Scheduler.config()
`
and I cannot find something related to this error.

Comment: Do you run it as `iex -S mix`?

Comment: Just these first attempts, once it's working I will create a function as part of a module within my project. Do you recommend me other strategy?